# How to insert data from a dictionary into an existing Excel file?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to insert dictionary data into an existing Excel file using openpyxl library.

I tried the following code but it returns

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/home/user/Downloads/copy_test.xlsx')
cell_sheet = wb.active
# print(cell_sheet)  
# print(cell_sheet.merged_cells.ranges)



start_row = 11
start_column = 2

data = {"Electricians" : {"Name of the electricians":{"phone_no": "7684930462"}} 
elect_data = data.get("Electricians", {})
for k,v in elect_data.items():
        cell_sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = k
        cell_sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column+1).value = v['phone_no']
        start_row += 1
        

wb.save("/home/user/Downloads/copy_test.xlsx")
```

Error: `MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only`
thanks.

Comment: `except` can't come after `finally`...

Comment: Edited in the code

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Your question is not clear

Comment: Hope it is clear now.

Comment: How can we help without the full error and without a [mre]? The error you get is probably from the line `cell_sheet["B11:B19"], cell_sheet["E11:E19"] = tuple(data.get("Mark Twain", "").values())` but we can't help without a [mre] of what `data` is...

Comment: apologize for the unclear code. Now I modified it.